# Load model by headless viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk

I have tried setting up Forge Viewer in headless mode using the following link: https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v6/tutorials/headless.

I have hard-coded the URN and the access token but the model is not displaying.

Please provide any sample source code to load the model.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a couple of tips:

1. Check the browser console. Perhaps the URN or the access token is incorrect, which is why the model does not load.
2. The link you're working with is for an older version of Forge Viewer (v6). I'd suggest using version 7.*. Try using this basic app as a starting point: https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-basic-app, and replace this [line of code](https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-basic-app/blob/develop/public/main.js#L2):

```js
const viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D(document.getElementById('preview'));
```

with

```js
const viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.Viewer3D(document.getElementById('preview'));
```

With this I've been able to load a model with a headless viewer:

[image]